# Karate- Gatling: Not able to run scenarios based on tags

Tags: scala, karate

I am trying to run performance test on scenario tagged as perf from the below feature file-

```
@tag1 @tag2 @tag3

**background:**
user login

@tag4 @perf
**scenario1:**

@tag4
**scenario2:**
```

Below is my .scala file setup-

```
class PerfTest extends Simulation {

  val protocol = karateProtocol()


  val getTags = scenario("Name goes here").exec(karateFeature("classpath:filepath"))

  setUp(
    getTags.inject(
      atOnceUsers(1)
      ).protocols(protocol)
  )
```

I have tried passing the tags from command line and as well as passing the tag as argument in exec method in scala setup.

**Terminal command-**

`mvn clean test-compile gatling:test "-Dkarate.env={env}" "-Dkarate.options= --tags @perf"`

**.scala update:-** I have also tried passing the tag as an argument in the karate execute.

```
 val getTags = scenario("Name goes here").exec(karateFeature("classpath:filepath", "@perf"))
```

Both scenarios are being executed with either approach. Any pointers how i can force only the test with tag perf to run?

Comment: if what is documented here is not working, it may be a bug: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#ignore-tags - so I personally think the best way forward is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share the finding here. I realized it is working fine when i am passing the tag info in .scala file.

My scenario with perf tag was a combination of GET and POST call as i needed some data from GET call to pass in POST call. That's why i was seeing both calls when running performance test.

I did not find any reference in karate gatling documentation for passing tags in terminal execution command. So i am assuming that might not be a valid case.